# Stopping a guessing game after correct answer

Tags: python

I have to write code for a guessing game and I cannot use loops. I must make the computer choose a random number between 1 and 32 which I have done, the user must make guesses and try get this number. After the user has correctly got the number how do I write some code that stops the game? You only get 5 tries. Here is my code:

```
import random

random.seed()

number = round((random.random()*32)+0.5)


def G():
    if guess > number:
        print("Lower...")
    else:
        print("Higher...")
        return False
  
def W():
    print("Correct!")
    print("You win!")
    return True


guess = int(input("Take a guess"))
if guess==number:
    W()
else:
    G()

guess = int(input("Try again"))
if guess==number:
    W()
else:
    G()

guess = int(input("Try again"))
if guess==number:
    W()
else:
    G()

guess = int(input("Try again"))
if guess==number:
    W()
else:
    G()

guess = int(input("Try again"))
if guess==number:
    W()
else:
    print("You lose!")
```

Comment: In W(),p put in some winning message and then exit().

Answer (score 1):

You should use recursive function so you can define the number of try to whatever value you want not having to duplicate lines :

```
def findNumber(numToFind,nbTries):
    guess = int(input("Take a guess : "))

    if guess == numToFind:
        return True

    if guess > numToFind:
        print("Lower...")
    else:
        print("Higher...")

    if nbTries <= 1:
        return False

    return findNumber(numToFind,nbTries-1)

result = findNumber(number,5)
if result:
    print("Correct!")
    print("You win!")
else:
    print("You loose:")
```

Comment: Thanks mate this works perfect.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `exit()` to stop script execution.

You could call `exit(0)` to exit the script showing no errors.

Answer (score 0):

I would write as follows - when you start *copy-and-paste* activity of parts of your code, something is not right:

```
def G(guess):
    if guess > number:
        print("Lower...")
    else:
        print("Higher...")
        return False

def W():
    print("Correct!")
    print("You win!")
    return True

def take_a_guess(guess, attempt_number = 1, max_attempts = 5):
    if guess == number:
        W()
        return
    else:
        G(guess)
    if attempt_number == max_attempts:
        print("You lost")
        return
    else:
        attempt_number += 1
        guess = int(input("Try again: "))   
        take_a_guess(guess, attempt_number, max_attempts) 



MAX_NUMBER_ATTEMPTS = 5

guess = int(input("Take a guess: "))
take_a_guess(guess, 1, MAX_NUMBER_ATTEMPTS)
```

Comment: OP said not to use loop. Correct your code. I've not downvoted your answer

Comment: @AbhijitShirwal It is ambiguous whether loops include recursive functions as recursive functions operate differently under the hood compared to for/while loops

Comment: @PeterWhite for clarity, my initial answer included a loop (I misread OP question - and honestly when I see code repeated over and over is stronger than me :-) ). So AbhijitShirwal comment was spot on!

Comment: @nikeros loved your honesty 

Comment: New to coding, when it says don't use loops it's things like while and for loops.

Answer (score 0):

When they say it cannot use loops, does that include recursive functions?

```
import random

random.seed() # redundant if you don't give it a seed value

number = random.randint(1,32) # This is the more appropriate function if you want integers

def make_guess(): # use descriptive function names
    guess = int(input("Take a guess"))
    if guess > number:
        print("Lower...")
    elif guess < number:
        print("Higher...")
    return guess 

def next_round(tries = 0):
    tries += 1
    guess = make_guess()
    if guess == number:
      print("Correct!\nYou win!")
      return
    elif tries >= 5:
      print("You lose!")
      return
    else:
      print("Try again")
      next_round(tries)
    
next_round()
```

I would also add some error handling in case the user enters a non-numeric input. You could make it end the game gracefully with a message telling them to use numbers, or even better, make it so they get that message and the game continues without consuming one of their tries. But I will leave that to you.

Comment: Sorry but I dont know what a recursive function is! It means specifically while and for loops.